# erroneous fields in wicket validation

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I'm trying to make my text fields erroneous when validation fails for a form component.
I'm adding an "error" value to my textfield class attribute which makes it red.

I do this by overriding the onValidate() method on the form and loping my components to see if they have errors.

```
@Override
    protected void onValidate() {
        super.onValidate();
        Iterator<Component> compIter = iterator();
        while(compIter.hasNext()) {
            final Component comp = compIter.next();
            if(comp instanceof AbstractTextComponent<?>) {
                comp.add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String getObject() {
                        return (comp.hasErrorMessage())?"error":"";
                    }
                }, " "));
            }
        }
    }
```

This works, but when I look at the generated HTML:

```
<input id="user_username" class="normal error error error" type="text" name="user.userName" value="stijn" maxlength="25" wicket:id="user.userName">
```

It generates the error value 3 times.
What am I doing wrong?

Is this the best way to accomplish this in wicket or are there better ways???

thx,
Koen

Comment: you could use the debugger and step through the code to see why `onValidate()` gets called 3 times

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it prints 3 times "error". Instead of writting your own tool you could use this one.
https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/automatic-styling-of-form-errors.html

Comment: There is also this presentation 'forms with flair' http://code.google.com/p/londonwicket/downloads/detail?name=LondonWicket-FormsWithFlair.pdf&can=2&q=